# Angular gzip json file automatically : Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"

Tags: json, angularjs, gzip

I use a gzip json static file on my server (actually, it's my test server) and the data i receive is always compressed.

Here is my code :

```
    $http({ 
      url :'app/assets/json/makes2v.json.gz',
      method: "GET",
      headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip' }})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

I use angular 1.3.15 and Chrome.

In the console I have this error:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 27):

You shouldn't set the request header "Accept-Encoding". This is set automatically by the browser. See this [Q&A](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22217/which-browsers-handle-content-encoding-gzip-and-which-of-them-has-any-special) for a list a browsers that accept gzip.

On the server side, you will need to set the Content-Encoding to:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Then the response should be automatically decompressed by the browser.

Comment: Actually, i use a test server launched via gulp i will try to do that if it possible and give the feedback. Thanks

Comment: What if this is a CORS request from my javascript? Will the browser automatically handle this? How can I verify that it is getting compressed data in the response?

Comment: Yes the same still holds true. To check the response, simply use the browser's dev console or a traffic inspection tool (ie: fiddler). Look at the repsonse header for "Content-Encoding: gzip" or the encoding of interest.