# Parsing json in gz files from a local directory through ajax - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, gzip

I am trying to read a json present in data.gz using angularJS's $http service. But I only get strange symbols and characters as a response. I am currently running the app locally in a nodeJS server. Am I missing something in here?

```
$http({ 
  url: 'systemRes.10.gz',
  method: 'GET'
})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log(response.data); //shows strange characters
});
```

[Click to view the strange characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMKjI.jpg)

Since , the file is in a local directory , setting headers to the following causes an error : *Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"*

```
headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip' }
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463340/angular-gunzip-json-file-automatically-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-accept-en ?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka no errors

Comment: @JordanQuagliatini kind of. but without errors

Comment: @haribalaji, according to the answer I linked, if you try to access a local file you will lack the `Content-Encoding` header, which will prevent the browser from unzipping the file. Actually, I tried to use `fetch` on Chrome and it prevented me from doing it. A solution may come from serving your file and providing the header together with the file.

Comment: @JordanQuagliatini , Yes Jordan . I agree . I think there is nothing we could do other that using a Content-Encoding header .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to access a local gz file will not provide the `Content-Encoding` header which is mandatory for the browser to unzip the file.

This is confirmed by this previous post -> [Angular gunzip json file automatically : Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463340/angular-gunzip-json-file-automatically-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-accept-en)

You should try to serve your file with a proper file server like nginx or apache, if you need to use your js file in production.
Otherwise if it is for a one-time script you should consider using [http-server](https://npmjs.com/http-server), which provide the `-g` option, serving your gzipped version of the file. For example, if your file is `systemRes.10.json.gz` then by launching `http-server` in your folder with

```
$ npm i http-server
$ node_modules/.bin/http-server -g
```

You could write the following js script (with fetch, but $http behaviour should be identical)

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/systemRes.10.json')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

I tested it and it provides the `Content-Encoding` header, so you should be good for your tests.

Comment: i tried it, but the server still does not provide Content-encoding header . It provides content-type:application/gzip though.

Comment: if you try to fetch directly the gz file it does indeed provide a `Content-Type: application/gzip`, but if instead of fetching the gz file you fetch the name of the file without the gz (as stated in my answer) it should work.

Namely try `fetch('http://localhost:8080/filename')` instead of `fetch('http://localhost:8080/filename.gz')`, the `-g` option of http-server handle it

Comment: That worked @Jordan. What if the archive name and the file present in it were different ? Say systemRes.10.gz contains data.json .

Comment: The browser doesn't care about the original name of the file, only the data is important to it. If your gz file contains well formatted JSON data, then using `JSON.parse` or `response.json` will give you full access to your json data. Usually modern web server gzip automatically content before sending it to client, you don't have to do it by hand, here's why you can't unzip a file with JS.

Comment: That makes sense. @Jordan Quagliatini